# Two dimensional list to one

Tags: python-3.x

I have multiple dimension list output I want to turn it to one dimension.

```
   a = [1,0,3,0,5,0]

   new_list = []

   l = [2,4,6]



   for i in a:
     new_list.append(l)



    print(new_list)

    #[[2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Comment: You want to flatten `new_list`?

Comment: What's your _expected_ output again? Why are you appending `l` over and over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `list-comprehension`:

```
s = [[2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6]]

print([x for subl in s for x in subl])
```

OUTPUT:

```
[2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You really are ought to `extend` the list, instead of `append` if you want a flat list to begin with. But if you already have it, the quickest and safest would be to use itertools:

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(your_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it recursively:

```
def flatten(s):
    if s == []:
        return s
    if isinstance(s[0], list):
        return flatten(s[0]) + flatten(s[1:])
    return s[:1] + flatten(s[1:])

l = [[2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6]]
res = flatten(l)
print(res) # prints [2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6]
```